# Body Deformates In Weird Ways When Bone is Rotated

Tags: rigging, bones

I have made a human model for my game, i have rigged it but now when I move any of the bones the player starts to deform in a really weird way, I have been searching for how t ofix it but i couldn't find anything useful, also whenever I try to move one of the bones with "g" it only starts to rotate and won't move properly.

plese help[image]

Comment: It's hard to help you when your question is hard to comprehend. Try adding some screenshots of the issue (just saying "something weird happens" doesn't explain what happens), and check your spelling also :)

Answer (score 0):

From your Screenshot i can tell that a lot of vertices are assigned to the Vertex group/Bone from the lower arm (or the corresponding hand/fingers). You should be able to see this influence if you go into Weight Paint mode and select those bones.

First I recommend going into wireframe mode and selecting every face you know, shouldn't be influenced by these bones at all. Then hit "Remove" for the Vertex Groups of the Bones in the corresponding lower Arm and Hand. This way those Bones won't effect Areas they aren't supposed to.

[image]

After that you'll have to balance the influence from the upper and lower arm in Weight Paint Mode, so it bends in a natural way.

Comment: This seems to have been the issue, thanks. Now I'm going to select evyr single bone and wieght paint :/